# zip files in all directories and subfolders without the folder itself

Tags: command-line, zip

I need to recursively zip the individual files itself in the directory path and its sub folders without zipping the folders or directory.  I also need to exclude certain file types (more then one).

How can I do this in Linux using ZIP?

Here is the modified script (thanks Ravexina).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"
dir=/home/fjaffer/temp
#cd "${dir}"
#cd $(echo $dir | tr -d '\r')
cd "$dir"
find -not -iname '*.txt' -type f | while read -r file_name; \
do zip "$(dir "$file_name")".zip "$file_name" ; done
```

Output:
line 8 zip command not found.

Comment: Do you want **one** *.zip file with all the files below a certain root directory or several *.gz files (one for each file)? // What should happen when two files in different directories have the same name?

Comment: No.  I need a zip file for each file in the directory or sub folders but not zip the directory and sub folder.

Comment: Thank you Ravexina.  I'm sorry if this is a silly question, would you mind clarifying what the "realpath" or $file_name" would be in an example.  I tried this syntax and I get the error "line 8 zip not found".  I'll edit my original question and place the script in there.

Comment: @FeminaJaffer seems you don't have `zip` installed, install it using: `sudo apt install zip`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with something like this:

```
find -not -iname '*.mp3' -type f | while read -r file_name; \
do zip "$(realpath "$file_name")".zip "$file_name" ; done
```

It will zips all files in their directory each separately other that of "mp3" files.

You can exclude other type of files too, for example, zip and mp3 files:

```
find -not -iname '*.mp3' -not -iname '*.zip' -type f
```

---

So this structure:

```
.
└── a
    ├── 1
    │   └── 1.mp3
    └── 2
        ├── 1.jpg
        ├── 1.mp3
        └── 1.mpv
```

would become:

```
.
└── a
    ├── 1
    │   └── 1.mp3
    └── 2
        ├── 1.jpg
        ├── 1.jpg.zip
        ├── 1.mp3
        ├── 1.mpv
        └── 1.mpv.zip
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will give this a try.  If it is all files than for filename I can use the wildcard option, such as *.* correct?  How would I add a counter...lets say I want the number of total directories and just zip files for 10 directories/subfolders files at a time?

Comment: It's not that smart of script, you can change the while with a for or add a counter as you already said your self and break the while after it reaches a number.  check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638670/adding-counter-in-shell-script

Comment: @FeminaJaffer You can also accept the answer by clicking on the gray tick if you think it was helpful to you.